# Need guideline about IOS notification process with php api

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm php developer, and i developed an api which is fetching the data from database and converting into json encode for ios app.

According to ios developer ios app hitting api file for notification once user open the app and kill it.

**What we need to do?**

According to requirement once ios app hit the api and received the data from database then ios app should not received the data again till 20 minutes, in other words i can say that app shouldn't hit again the api file.

**What I wanted to know?**

I want to know is this possible to do that above mention task (`IOS app shouldn't received any notification or data from server till 20 minutes once received it.`) in ios app. Ios developer said to me its not possible inside the app, it can be done by server and php side. Can anyone guide me its possible inside the app ? I would like to appreciate.

Comment: Give me the clarification . you are talking about "Push-notification Service " , or once ios app hit the api and received the data from database (just api hit)

Comment: @srinivasn Actually once ios hit the api, then api retrieve the data from server . In this way user notified that there is something for you.. This is flow

Comment: Hit the api make the time limit it is possible in local , In app you need to make the logic for hit the service after 20mins , ex: NSTimer , after delay , scheduler methods are there you can check it

Comment: @srinivasn Thank you so much for guideline `NSTimer` function is working on both side background and foreground process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible from iOS app. Developer can use NSTimer and set time limit to 20 mins.

Comment: Thank you so much for guideline NSTimer function is working on both side background and foreground process?

Comment: @Mr.Developer NO. NSTimer will not work in background. You can  do one thing. Keep track of timer before app enters into background, when app comes to foreground calculate the difference between current time and saved timer and if its greater than or equal to 20, hit your API again.

Comment: Thank you so much, just one more, is above logic will be work if user open and kill the app again again ?

Comment: Yes. Only small change you will have to make is, rather than storing timer count in any variable store it in NSUserDefaults, so that after killing app also, the data will be persisted.

Comment: @Mr.Developer If my answer helped you then you can mark it as correct.